# Pickle TypeError inside numpy.save()

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy

I have a function to compute features and then save the features into pickle.

```
test_knn_feats = NNF.predict(X_test) 
np.save('data/knn_feats_%s_test.npy' % metric , test_knn_feats)
```

In the function, if `n_jobs` is more than 1, then code below will execute.

```
fest_feats =[]
pool = Pool(processes = self.n_jobs) 
for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    test_feats.append(pool.apply_async(self.get_features_for_one(X[i:i+1])))
pool.close()
pool.join()

return np.vstack(test_feats)
```

However, there is error occur:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-4f707b7cd533> in <module>()
     12     print(test_knn_feats)
     13     # Dump the features to disk
---> 14     np.save('data/knn_feats_%s_test.npy' % metric , test_knn_feats)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in save(file, arr, allow_pickle, fix_imports)
    507         arr = np.asanyarray(arr)
    508         format.write_array(fid, arr, allow_pickle=allow_pickle,
--> 509                            pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
    510     finally:
    511         if own_fid:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py in write_array(fp, array, version, allow_pickle, pickle_kwargs)
    574         if pickle_kwargs is None:
    575             pickle_kwargs = {}
--> 576         pickle.dump(array, fp, protocol=2, **pickle_kwargs)
    577     elif array.flags.f_contiguous and not array.flags.c_contiguous:
    578         if isfileobj(fp):
```

The function `get_features_for_one` will return a list, shown below.

```
...
knn_feats = np.hstack(return_list)
assert knn_feats.shape == (239,) or knn_feats.shape == (239, 1)
return knn_feats
```

*Update:

```
test_feats =[]      
pool = Pool(processes = self.n_jobs) 
for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    test_feats.append(pool.apply_async(self.get_features_for_one, (X[i:i+1],)))
test_feats= [res.get() for res in test_feats]        
pool.close()
pool.join()
return np.vstack(test_feats)
```

Comment: What is `test_knn_feats.dtype` before you save it?  What does multithreading have to do with this?  Are you saying the code works if run without multithreading?

Comment: When I print it, it displays:
[[<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x7f1bb03ae5c0>]
 [<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x7f1bb02fe240>]
 [<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x7f1bb02fe2b0>]
 ..., 
 [<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x7f1bb17b62b0>]
 [<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x7f1bb17b63c8>]
 [<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x7f1bb17b6518>]]

Comment: @JohnZwinck  it is `object` dtype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major bugs here:

```
test_feats =[] # you called it fest_feats, I assume a typo
pool = Pool(processes = self.n_jobs) 
for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    test_feats.append(pool.apply_async(self.get_features_for_one(X[i:i+1])))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

return np.vstack(test_feats)
```

1. First, you create a Pool.  Then for each `i` you submit one job and then close & join the pool.  You should only close & join the pool once, at the end, outside the loop.
2. test_feats ends up being a list of "futures", not actual data.  So `vstack()` on them makes no sense.  You need to call `get()` on each future to get the result of `get_features_for_one()` and then pass that list to `vstack()`.  For example `np.vstack([res.get() for res in test_feats])`.

In short, you problem has nothing to do with the TypeError that you eventually receive from `numpy.save()`--your problem is that your logic is completely broken and your data is not what you think it is.

Comment: Ahh there is a copy& paste mistake for first point. I close and join the pool outside the loop. I will try on 2nd point.

Comment: Tried with `test_feats = [res.get() for res in test_feats]`.  Having `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable` , I will take my time to debug it

Comment: @MervynLee: You're getting the new error because you're running code which is not what you've posted.  Stop doing that.

Comment: I try to print `res.ready()` and it returns True, but it will output the TypeError if I try to call `res.get()`